# Swift and Wordpress API: Wordpress API escapes some characters to unicode

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I'm copy-pasting 2 post title returned by Wordpress API:

`Haydarpaşa&#8217;da ortaya çıktı! Tam 1700 yıllık&#8230;`

`Pakistan&#8217;da terör saldırısı`

I create structs for categories/posts and other things and made them decodable, but these do not handle Unicodes. Here is an example; the struct I created for categories. (Struct for posts is too big, so I share category struct. They're all built on the same idea.)

```
struct WPCategory: Decodable {

  let id: Int
  let count: Int
  let description: String
  let link: URL
  let name: String
  let slug: String
  let taxonomy: WPCategoryTaxonomy
  let parent: Int

  enum WPCategoryTaxonomy: String, Codable {
    case category, postTag = "post_tag", navMenu = "nav_menu", linkCategory = "link_category", postFormat = "post_format"
  }

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, count, description, link, name, slug, taxonomy, parent, meta
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    count = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .count)
    description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
    let linkString  = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .link)
    guard let link = URL.init(string: linkString) else {
      throw WPAPIError.urlToStringFailed
    }
    self.link = link
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    slug = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .slug)
    taxonomy = try container.decode(WPCategoryTaxonomy.self, forKey: .taxonomy)
    parent = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .parent)
  }
}
```

I'm using Alamofire to get the data:

```
  func getCategories(page: Int = 1, onCompletion completionHandler: @escaping (_ categories: [WPCategory]?, _ totalPages: Int?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
    let request = alamofire.request(categoriesURL, method: .get, parameters: ["page": page, "per_page": 100, "exclude":"117"], encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).validate()
    request.responseData  { (response) in
      switch response.result {
      case .success(let result):
        guard let total = response.response?.allHeaderFields["x-wp-totalpages"] as? String else {
          completionHandler(nil, nil, WPAPIError.couldNotFetchTotalHeader)
          return
        }

        do {
          let categories = try JSONDecoder.init().decode([WPCategory].self, from: result)
          completionHandler(categories, Int(total), nil)
        } catch(let err) {
          completionHandler(nil, nil, err)
        }

      case .failure(let error):
        completionHandler(nil, nil, error)
      }
    }
  }
```

So, how can I handle these Unicode chars? Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You should better update the title and the text where using _Unicode_. Swift String is based on Unicode and Swift Standard Library or Apple's framework _handles_ Unicode properly.  So your title does not make sense. Something like `&#8217;` is called as _numeric character reference_ (or _numeric entity_ or _character entity_ , etc...), not as _Unicode_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this extension I wrote for it:

```
extension String {
    func htmlDocument() throws -> String {
        let data = self.data(using: .unicode)
        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: NSAttributedString.DocumentType] = [.documentType : .html]
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil).string
    }
}
```

So you can use it in your decoder like:

```
...
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name).htmlDocument()
...
```

Comment: It did not work at the beginning but instead `[NSAttributedString: NSAttributedString.DocumentType]` array should be `NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey` than everything is fine.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks to this extension you provided, I can decode all unicodes without using any hardcode from now on. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to process such an escaped string in Swift, you can convert it to a *normal* Unicode string.

So if entering the following code into a Swift playground:

```
import Foundation


func convert(escapedString: String) -> String {
    guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(&#([0-9]+);)",
                                               options: []) else { return escapedString }

    let escapedNSString = escapedString as NSString
    let matches: [NSTextCheckingResult] = regex.matches(in: escapedString,
                                                        options: [],
                                                        range: NSMakeRange(0, escapedString.count))
    var convertedString = escapedNSString

    for match in matches.reversed() {
        let matchString = escapedNSString.substring(with: match.range(at: 2))
        var replacement: String
        if let unicode = UnicodeScalar(Int(matchString)!) {
            replacement = String(unicode)
        } else {
            replacement = "?"
        }
        convertedString = convertedString.replacingCharacters(in: match.range, with: replacement) as NSString
    }
    return String(convertedString)
}


let str1 = "Haydarpaşa&#8217;da ortaya çıktı! Tam 1700 yıllık&#8230;"
print (convert(escapedString: str1))
let str2 = "Pakistan&#8217;da terör saldırısı"
print (convert(escapedString: str2))
```

so you will get as result:

```
Haydarpaşa’da ortaya çıktı! Tam 1700 yıllık…
Pakistan’da terör saldırısı
```

Comment: `for` loop on string is always bad practice! specially if it contains unicodes. be aware of that.

Comment: I agree with you, at least in some cases. But that's not the case here, take a quick look at the code: The for loop does *not* work on strings, but on the array of matches with regular expressions, which are of type `[NSTextCheckingResult]`. All string operations are based on Ranges and Apple methods, which are all Unicode safe ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As per @OOper suggestion better to update title and text where using unicode. swift string is based on the unicode and refer below link of documentation that's proof of swift standard Library or apple's framework handles unicode properly. so your mentioned titles does not make sense `&#8230; &#8217;` these are numeric character reference, not unicode char.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html